# How to create empty class in F#

Tags: f#

I know this is stupid question. I can create an empty class like the following in c#.

```
class Customer{}
```

But How can I do this in F#? This is my try

```
type Customer() =

   let _ = ()
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try

```
type Customer() = class end
```

Normally, you can leave the `class` and `end` tokens implicit and the compiler infers their presence at the beginning and end of the class's definition, but if the class is completely empty you'll need to specify them.  Likewise, you can use `struct end` and `interface end` to generate structs and interfaces.

Comment: I try 
type Customer = class end, without "()", works for me.

Comment: @Fred - yes, that will work too, but then your class won't have any accessible constructor within F#.

Comment: you are right, need to  have the "()" there,  need to see the IL to see how that works :).

Comment: `type IInterface = interface end` creates an empty interface, for those who need it.

Answer (score 11):

Yet another way:

```
type Customer = 
  new() = {}
```

Answer (score 10):

Another way to write an empty class (with a parameterless constructor), and I'm not sure how the resulting IL would look compared to @kvb's solution if different at all, is simply

```
type Customer() = do ()
```